# Mongodb, aggregate, use $lookup with a array on foreignfield

Tags: mongodb

```
//issues-collection
[
  {
     project: ObjectId("67"), // ref to a project
     id: 101,
     assignedTo: ObjectId("1212") // ref to a user
  }
]


//project-collection
[
  {
     _id: ObjectId("67"),
     title: "Proj 1",
     members: [
       {
          _id: ObjectId("213213"),
          user: ObjectId("1212"), // ref to a user
          discipline: "Architect"
       }
     ]  
  }
]
```

I need a query for the issue collection on the disciplin field from the project collection

The `$lookup` should be used. Something like this.

```
const getIssuesByDiscipline = (projectId, discpline: string) => {
   const res = mongoose.model("issues").aggregate([
     {
      $lookup: {
        from: "project",
        localField: "assignedTo",
        foreignField: "members.user",
        as: "project",
        //pipeline: ?
     }
   ]
},
```

}...

Not sure how to use $lookup when the foregin field is an array. Maybe something with `pipeline`?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

**MongoDB version 5.0 or higher**:

1. Use the `project` from `issues` collection to find the documents on `project` collection with the matching `_id`
2. Use the pipeline to `$filter` relevant `user`s

```
db.issues.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "project",
      localField: "project",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "project",
      let: {assignedTo: "$assignedTo"},
      pipeline: [
        {$project: {
            members: {$filter: {
                input: "$members",
                cond: {$eq: ["$$this.user", "$$assignedTo"]}
            }}
        }}
      ]
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q6esbbgaBBE)

**MongoDB versions before 5.0:**
Can't use both `localField, foreignField` with a pipeline. Instead, add another phase to the pipeline (as a first phase) to match the relevant documents:

```
db.issues.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "project",
      as: "project",
      let: {assignedTo: "$assignedTo", project: "$project"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$$project", "$_id"]}}},
        {$project: {
            members: {$filter: {
                input: "$members",
                cond: {$eq: ["$$this.user", "$$assignedTo"]}
            }}
        }}
      ]
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s380xNC2mZW)

Comment: Using mongo 4.2. Can you show the pipeline? Tried all kinds of combos but I don't get a match.

Comment: Updated the answer of MongoDB versions before 5.0 (4.2 should be OK)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add three stages. I unwinded and added field "discipline". So I can react it directly. Problem is, if assignedTo is null there are no hits at all. https://mongoplayground.net/p/-k-Ab9xIHdu . In the playground i commented out assignedTo and set it to null. Any way to fix this?

Comment: You can use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true` if you want. check [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) out.